# Macbook Air M1 losing functionality for some keys and Siri after a while

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, apple-silicon

I have a Macbook Air with M1 8C8G 16GB and latest macOS version.

It's all good, really great laptop and I love it but I have this problem of some function keys stopping functioning after a while up until a restart.

The first one is usually the F5 that is supposed to activate Siri(It's handy to ask the weather and do some conversions). Even if I put the Siri icon in the status bar and try to activate from there by clicking, Siri won't activate.

Next I lost the escape key. It's not working at the moment, I tried the accessibility to see if it's working there but no, even the software escape key is not working. External keyboard escape key is also not working, which convinces me that it's not a hardware issue.

I usually have heavy on the RAM workload(Xcode and the iOS simulators eat RAM like candy) that I suspect is the prime reason. I also have uptime that usually spans from macOS update to macOS update, currently at over 20 days and I intend to keep it like that, therefore I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to restart my computer each time something stops working.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried closing XCode and the simulators - i.e. freeing up the RAM - does it work then [i.e. prove / disprove your theory].  My first thought is does it have the butterfly keyboard - they are notorious at failing due to dust - I've had two that the keyboards needed to be replaced [but apple will do that].

Comment: Tried closing all the large apps, inlcuding Xcode and the simulators but it din't help. BTW, the new Macbook Air's don't have the butterfly keys - they were updated to the beloved and reliable scissor mechanism.

Comment: It's not clear whether Siri stops launching (by any means); or whether F5 stops working. But really you need to rule out hardware failure first. You may need to restart while testing the cause of the problem; but lengthy uptimes should not cause problems in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It can be remedied by going to System Settings > Siri and unchecking an re-checking the 'Enable Ask Siri'. But it's still keeps coming back. Siri stops working and the escape key. So annoying.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/326649)

Comment: I know it doesn't solve the problem, but it's clearly an easier way to temporarily fix it then what the OP was doing. If that's not helpful, then I'll be done with this website. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: As a temporary solution, your "answer" is more of a comment and not a full-fledged solution. Once you get enough reputation then you will be able to comment. Invest some time in getting to know the site by taking the [tour].